# Run a function on first run of a air application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air

I want to call a function only when the air application is run on a system for the first time after installation. Is there something I can check to determine this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is use the `SharedObject` interface and store a value that tells you that you have done something already.  Something like this, perhaps?

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("appName.breadcrumb");
if(!so.data.initialized) {
    doYourStuff();
    so.data.initialized = true;
}
```

Does that work for you?